# Jpa unidirectional @OneToOne where columns should be created in another table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have Employee and Department requirement, where I want a field department in the employee entity, but I want department to hold foreign key, rather than employee holding the DEPT_ID. The later can be easily achieved using @JoinColumn. Mapped by is not an option, as it is unidirectional.

Do you know if there is any way to do so?

Comment: This is only possible if you have only one employee assigned a department. Is it so?

Comment: makes no sense, at all

Comment: Yes ujulu, department table is actually holding head of department, and there can be only one HOD. And thats why we have one to one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the JoinColumn you should use and set the attributes of the annotation the correct way.

```
class Department {

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="ID",referencedColumnName = "here comes the foreign key departmentID ")
  Employee employee;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, I have a requirement to keep department in the employee entity.

Comment: Well you just reverse them then as I just did.